# Distribution strategy to minimize the maximum value in an array

Tags: algorithm

Recently, I come across this problem in solving another problem. I have a solution myself. But I'm not quite satisfied with its time complexity. So, I'm turning to you guys for a possible better solution. The problem is as follows:

Suppose there is an integer array `int arr[N]`. I have an integer value `val` in my hand to distribute to `arr`. For example, I can increase `arr[0]` by `val`, or `arr[2]` by `1` and `arr[3]` by `val - 1`, and so on. The goal is to minimize the maximum value in `arr` after the distribution. There may be multiple solutions, and anyone will just do.

My current solution is as follows. It's trivial and takes `O(val)` time. I have a feeling that a better solution exists.

```
for (int i = 0; i < val; ++i) {
  // increase the minimum value in arr by 1
}
```

Comment: In your approach you forgot to take into account the complexity of finding the minimum element in `arr`, so it is `O(val * cost_to_find_min)`. To find minimum you can use heap or sort the elements in the beginning and try to keep them balanced, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a linear-time algorithm. First try to increase everything to the current max. If we have to keep going, distribute the rest as evenly as possible. In untested Python:

```
def distribute(arr, val):
    maxarr = max(arr)
    for x in arr:
        val -= min(maxarr - x, val)
    return maxarr - (-val) // len(arr)
```

The double minus silliness is to get ceiling division.